# "Short" calibration

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, vna

The following section from [ST Micro's AN4974 - 'Antenna Matching'](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00347152-antenna-matching-for-st25r3911bst25r391x-devices-stmicroelectronics.pdf) app note is a bit of a mystery.

Is there a VNA / network analyzer guru out there who can tell me what the 4th line there is saying?  I don't understand the jargon.  I'm familiar with the short/open/50ohm termination method of calibrating a VNA, and I know a minimum about S(i,j) parameters, Smith charts and such.  They're using a single-turn standard coil to examine a multi-turn tag coil via induction.

> 7.3 Verification of the Q factor in the frequency domain
> The Q factor can be measured using a vector network analyzer and an ISO10373-6
> Class 1-3 calibration coil.
>
> 1. The network analyzer shall be calibrated for a frequency sweep from about 10 to 20
>    MHz
> 2. S11 measurement in log mag format shall be displayed.
> 3. The calibration coil is connected to the VNA.
> 4. “Short” calibration of the coil and conversion to “Z: Reflection”
> 5. Set marker 1 and enable the bandwidth/Q factor measurement
> 6. Place the PCD antenna on the measurement coil

Comment: Can you provide a link to the full document?

Comment: It might mean short as opposed to long, full or thorough, rather than short as opposed to open. After all, it's only measuring a ratio of frequencies, not an accurate power level.

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00347152-antenna-matching-for-st25r3911bst25r391x-devices-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: I'm told by ST that "The idea is to calibrate away the characteristics of the pickup coil, and be able to only sense the characteristic of the reader or tag antenna - since the antenna is still connected during the "short" calibration."